# brew update - too many open files

Tags: ruby, sinatra, homebrew, macos-high-sierra

This question has been asked about hundredths of times and I am trying to resolve using google and SO but actually none of the solutions actually helps.

for example, like these one:

[Os x terminal, ssh , and too many open files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095796/os-x-terminal-ssh-and-too-many-open-files#10097735)

my output (-n was 256)

```
ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 7168
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 1
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 709
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
```

and the error is the same.

I also tryied to kill all the processess which took much open files from these post: https://superuser.com/questions/433746/is-there-a-fix-for-the-too-many-open-files-in-system-error-on-os-x-10-7-1

but this didn't help.

I also try to turn my computer off and on again. That didn't help either.
I have no idea what i need to do.

**origin:**

I had a ruby script with rufus_scheduler gem and ibm_db which downloads data at specified time - worked ok until I got an interpreter error which claimed to be a bug (on the same code which was ok). (i have no record, rerun it.) So I was thinking about reinstalling ruby(2.3.0, 2.4.0) but it failed with error:

```
blah blah make sure brew update is working blah blah
```

so I ended up trying brew update and obviously, it didn't work.

any help apprieciated. thank you very much.

**specs:** os x 10.13.3 - high sierra

**ruby:** tried on 2.3.0, 2.4.0

**gemfile:**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "2.4.0"
gem 'sinatra', '~> 2.0.0'
gem 'json'
gem 'couchrest_model'
gem 'sinatra-config-file'
gem 'rufus-scheduler'
gem 'ibm_db'
```